# why python regex is not finding numbers?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find numbers in a string.

```
import re

text = "42 ttt 1,234 uuu 6,789,001"

finder = re.compile(r'\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*')
print(re.findall(finder, text))
```

It returns this:
`['', ',234', ',745']`

What's wrong with regex?

How can I get `['42', '1,234', '6,789,745']`?

Note: I'm getting correct result at https://regexr.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You indicate with parentheses `(...)` what the groups are that should be captured by the regex.

In your case, you only capture the part *after* (and including) the first comma. Instead, you can capture the whole number by putting a group around everything, and make the parentheses you need for `*` *non-capturing* through an initial `?:`, like so:

```
r'(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)'
```

This gives the correct result:

```py
>>> print(re.findall(finder, text))
['42', '1,234', '6,789,001']
```

Comment: yeah it seems to work, but do you have any idea why my original regex is working at https://regexr.com but not at python?

Comment: yes I realised that `,,` your one is correct 

Comment: @Kolom [This is `re.findall` specific behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall): "If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups". regexr.com highlights the whole match instead.

Comment: @Dion Yeah but, why it's not matching the first number though: 42

Comment: It is matching the first number, it just returns you the empty group `(,\d{3})*` (this is why you get an empty string as first result)

Answer (score 0):

you just need to change your finder like this.

```
finder = re.compile(r'\d+\,?\d+,?\d*')
```

Comment: This matches '123,12,1', though :)

Comment: yes, your answer is best solution. 
(?:,\d{3})* 
Non-capturing group (?:,\d{3})*
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
, matches the character , literally (case sensitive)